# Windows Forms focus event

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I have a tabbed Form with an overridden OnActivated method. When I leave my application (Alt-Tab) and go back to my application, the OnActivated method isn't triggered.

Is there another method or event which can be used to catch this? I would like to have an event on the Form. If this is not possible, maybe there's an event on the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate is part of the form creation / Display process

Enter or Gotfocus is what you want, but usually on the control that had focus when you Alt tabbed out.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)

for further details

If you tell us what you want to happen and may be why, there may be a better way.